# Using bootstrap, how do you get columns to clear properly?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

http://darrenbachan.com/playground/syau/index.html#!/

I know you guys expect code in here to help resolve problems, but I'm using bootstrap, so it's their code. If you take a look at the roster section the heights are all messed up. I had two hacky solutions, one was going in and specifically placing a class on certain divs with clear:both, the other solution was applying a fixed height onto the columns. I wanted something dynamic.

Right now certain roster members are not placed correctly, it should be a 4 up column grid.

Also, to avoid creating two posts. I have a second issue. I cannot figure out how to put a background image on my video. My css is:

```
.full-img {
        background: url('../img/fallback.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Another issue I'm having is centering the .banner-text div vertically, my code for that was:

```
.banner-text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
    text-align: left;
    display: table;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    float: left;
}
.banner-text h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But that didnt work, which is why I have padding on the div to fake it.

I'm sort of new to this whole front-end stuff, so I'd be open to any suggestions to anything else if you guys pick up on anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This situation happens when columns have variable heights. Bootstrap uses the `float` property to align columns horizontally. This allows us to have columns that wrap to the next line when the total column size is greater than 12. Unfortunately, if any column in one line has a larger height than the others, you will notice that columns in the next line will start after the larger column from the previous line.

The solution to this problem has traditionally been to use a "clearfix". A div that uses the `clear:both` declaration that moves the next element to the bottom of all previous floating elements.

Bootstrap has a helper class called `.clearfix` that you should put in an empty div **after every 12 column units**. In your case, this means after ever 4 `.col-md-3`  (since 4 × `.col-md-3` = 12), after every 3 `.col-sm-4` (since 3 × `.col-sm-4` = 12), and after every 2 `.col-xs-6` (since 2 × `.col-xs-6` = 12). But the clearfix should only take effect when the browser is at the corresponding viewport size. The way you do that is by using the `visible-lg-block`, `visible-md-block`, `visible-sm-block` and `visible-xs-block` classes so they only have effect at the appropriate sizes.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div><div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div><div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div><div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div><div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"></div><div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block"></div>
```

Note where multiple `visible-*-block` classes are used because of common multiples.

### Note for Bootstrap 4:

This solution is not needed anymore since Bootstrap 4 uses the newer flexbox layout model instead of floats.

### For the vertical alignment of the banner text:

It looks you were on the right track, you just have to give the `.banner-text` a 100% height, and you need to do the same for the `.row` and `.container` that wraps it.

So basically,

```
.banner-text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 200;
    text-align: left;
    display: table;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    float: left;
    height:100%
}
.banner-text h1 {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And then give the row and container above it a `height:100%`. You could give them IDs so you can target them in css or just do it inline.

Comment: I've tried adding the visible-*-block divs but it still did nothing. I also made the elements you mentioned height:100% but it seems that I lost the button I had in the process. I've pushed the code online so you can see.

Comment: I've gotten visible-sm-block and visible-xs-block working but md-block doesn't for some reason.

Comment: @DarrenBachan Ah, you should also add a `visible-lg-block` on all the divs that have a `visible-md-block`. Then it should work. Also, you didn't include the ones that have `visible-sm-block`, those go after every 4 columns. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @DarrenBachan Regarding the button, I don't remember where it was positioned the first time. I guess you could put it in a div that has `display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle;` to have it sit next to the text vertically-centered as well.

Comment: I had it in the .banner-text div all along and it disappeared. The button is floated right. I want it to hug the right and be on the baseline of the text on the left.

Comment: I forgot to mention, adding visible-lg-block did work, thanks! I still can't figure out the button though.

Answer (score 0):

For background image

```
background: url("../img/image.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

For `h1` you can set `width` & `height` for it and use `margin:auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's row class does this for you. You can either limit the number of elements per row, or you can explicitly set the height of each element and not use a row. The latter approach will allow you to vary the number of items across based on viewport size.

For an elaborate grid, it may be necessary to explicitly clear your floats using nth-child or even adding numeric classes of your own.

Comment: I was trying this

/*#roster-list div:nth-child(4)::after {
 content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}